# Some questions about Hermitian metric on complex manifold

Tags: riemannian-geometry, complex-geometry

Suppose $g$ is a Riemannian metric on a complex manifold  $X$ compatible with the almost complex structure. $g$ can be extended to $TX\otimes\mathbb{C}$, which is a Hermitian inner product: $<\lambda v,\mu w>_c:=\lambda\bar{\mu}g(v,w)$.

[Reference](http://web.stanford.edu/~tonyfeng/complex_manifolds.pdf) p.40-42.

My first question is if $g$ is not compatible with the almost complex structure, then if the extension is still Hermitian or what can we say about this extended inner product?

In contrast, on Ballmann's notes [Ballmann's notes](http://people.mpim-bonn.mpg.de/hwbllmnn/archiv/kaehler0609.pdf) p.42, if $g$ is a compatible Riemannian metric on $M$ and $\omega$ is the associated Kahler form, then $h = g + i\omega$ is a Hermitian metric on $TM$.  In this notes, the extended inner product is extended bi-linearly instead of sesquilinearly. Now what can we say about these two Hermitian extended inner products?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The answer to your first question is yes --  regardless of whether the metric $g$ is compatible with $J$, the section $H \in \Gamma(T^*X^{\otimes 2} \otimes \mathbb{C})$ defined by $H(\lambda v, \mu w):=\tfrac{1}{2}\lambda\overline{\mu}g(v,w)$ is a Hermitian metric. This is just because it is a smoothly varying Hermitian inner product on each fiber of $TX \otimes \mathbb{C}$. That having been said, $H$ will not necessarily play nicely with the holomorphic and antiholomorphic bundles, commonly denoted by $T^{1,0}X$ and $T^{0,1}X$. In fact, these two subbundles are $H$-orthogonal to one another if and only if $g$ is $J$-compatible. 
In the case that $g$ is not $J$-compatible, we will also no longer have the nice decomposition $H= g+i\omega$, which is the standard shorthand for the situation (indeed, there is no reason for the form define by 
$$(v+iJv,w+iJw) \mapsto g(v,w) + ig(Jv,w)$$
to be Hermitian if $g$ is not assumed to be compatible with $J$).
We will, however, still have an analogous decomposition $H= \tilde{g} + i\tilde{\omega}$, where 
$$\tilde{g}(v,w):=\tfrac{1}{2}\big(g(v,w)+g(Jv,Jw)\big)$$
and
$$\tilde{\omega}(v,w):=\tfrac{1}{2}\big(g(Jv,w)-g(v,Jw)\big).$$
As before, we have that $g=\tilde{g}$ and $\omega=\tilde{\omega}$ iff $g$ is compatible with $J$.

Please let me know if I can help clarify any of this. Differential geometry is rife with abuses of notation. Of course, as soon as one understands what is meant by the abusive notation, one happily adopts it. I am no exception =).

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Do you know any reference for what you said or which gives more details?  Also your $H$ is extended from $g$ by susquilieanr, however, there is another extension via bi-linear, say $h$, e.g. the answer of this post: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/216203/a-question-on-hermitian-metric-on-complex-manifold

Comment: I want to know the differences between these two extensions. Right now it seems to me that $h$ is not positive definite (since $h(\partial x_k+i\partial y_j,\partial x_k+i\partial y_j)$ may not be real), then I don't know if it's still a Hermitian metric

Comment: Danny -- I see what you're asking now. You're touching on a very valid source of confusion. The "bilinear extension" you're talking about is in fact $not$ a Hermitian metric. It's just the complexification of $g$. However, it is true, that given a Riemannian metric $g$, if we done by $g_{\mathbb{C}}$ its complexification, then the bilinear map $(v,w) \mapsto g_{\mathbb{C}}(v,\overline{w})$ is a Hermitian metric. Your confusion, I believe, is arising from the fact that authors often forget that you need to conjugate in the second factor in order to get your Hermitian metric.

Comment: The first poster in the question you linked in fact mentions this (starting where he says "a word of caution"). =)

Comment: Sorry I still feel confused, by this notes http://people.mpim-bonn.mpg.de/hwbllmnn/archiv/kaehler0609.pdf p.42, I feel confused with the definition of Hermitian metric now, isn't it defined on $TM_c$? But in this notes, it's defined on $TM$.

Comment: Also in remark 4.3, if $h$ is defined on $TM$, what does it mean by $h(iX,Y)$?

Comment: Moreover, the Hermtian form $H$ is defined on $T^{1,0}M$ or $TM$ or $TM_c$?

Comment: The $H$ that I define is defined on $TM \otimes \mathbb{C}$. In the notes you hyperlinked, $TM$ is being considered as a complex vector bundle, where multiplication by $i$ is given by $J$. I.e., if $M$ is a $2n$-dimensional real manifold and $TM$ has a complex structure $J$, then $TM$ can be thought of as a rank $n$ complex vector bundle.

Comment: Using the standard local trivialization, $\{\partial x_1,\partial y_1,\ldots,\partial x_n,\partial y_n\}$ (for $TM$ considered as a real bundle), a local trivialization of $TM$ considered as a complex vector bundle is just $\{\partial x_1,\ldots, \partial x_n\}$. We define multiplication by the complex number $a+ib$ on a vector $\sum_j \alpha_j \partial x_j$ to be $(a+ib) \sum_j \alpha_j \partial x_j := a\sum_j \alpha_j \partial x_j + bJ\sum_j \alpha_j \partial x_j$. Thus it makes sense to talk of a Hermitian metric on $TM$.

Comment: In remark 4.3, he's just saying supposing that $h$ is a Hermitian metric on $TM$ considered as a complex vector bundle in the way I just described.

Comment: I know $(TM,J)$ is isomorphic to $T^{1,0}M$, but I can't see why it's isomorphic to $TM$ with trivialisation $\{\partial x_i\}$.

Comment: Danny — the isomorphism between $TM$ and $T^{1,0}M$ you’re referring to takes $v \mapsto v+iJv$. Using the local trivialization for $TM$ as a complex vector bundle I just described, this isomorphism looks like $\partial x_i \mapsto \partial z_i$. This map extends to an automorphism of TM \otimes \mathbb{C} which is the missing link between the two ways to define a Hermitian metric you’ve encountered.

Comment: Thanks again and again, this is going to be last question, I feel confused with the decomposition $H=g+i\omega$ defined over $TM\times C$, it seems it's not well-defined, when we consider $H(a,b)=g(a,b)+i\omega(a,b)$, where $a,b\in TM\times C$, there is no definition for $g(a,b)$, and by definition, $H$ is extended by $g$, thus if $g(a,b)$ is defined, then $g(a,b)=H(a,b)$. Thus I wonder if this decomposition is defined on $TM$?

Comment: You're totally correct, Danny. I'm sorry. The decomposition $H=g+i\omega$ and $H=\tilde{g}+i \tilde{\omega}$ that I mentioned in my answer used the standard identification of $T^{1,0}M$ with $TM$ that I mentioned in my earlier comments.. You're totally right for pointing it out -- when one is trying to clear up somebody else's confusion about which convention is being used where, one shouldn't be switching back and forth between conventions without warning them. Sorry!